# "Depth" with moving Flash sprites

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, depth

I've seen this done before, but I don't know the correct terminology...how do you change the "layer" a Flash sprite is in depending on where it is, whether it is (or looks like) it is in front or behind a sprite.

In other words, how can one accomplish "depth" with Flash sprites?

Take a look at my current problem:

[image]

Note how the one polar bear is on top of every other polar bear when walking upwards.

I've came across this: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?351346-Swap-depth-of-Movieclip-based-on-Y-location, but the code was of no help to me (I tried using it, but nothing changed).

This is an example of what I want to accomplish (note how the snail moves behind and in front of the sprites depending on its position):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of z-sorting. Basically all you need to do in AS3 is store your `Sprites` in an array and sort it based on the `y` position of each sprite. Then you loop through the array and add the sprites to the stage or another `DisplayObject` continuously. You might think adding them like this is bad, but it's the normal way to do it.

I made a demo for you on wonderfl : http://wonderfl.net/c/f54p

And here is the source code with a few comments:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.*;

public class FlashTest extends Sprite {

    private var boxes:Array;
    private var BOX_NUM:int = 20;
    public function FlashTest() {
        var box:Box;

        boxes = [];

        // create a bunch of boxes and add them
        for(var i:int = 0; i < BOX_NUM; i++){
           box = new Box();
           boxes.push(box);
           addChild(box);   
        }
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoop);
    }

    private function onLoop(e:Event):void{
        // sort boxes based on the y property of each sprite
        boxes.sortOn("y", Array.NUMERIC);    
        for(var i:int = 0; i < BOX_NUM; i++){
          // scale the boxes so the effect is easier to see
          boxes[i].scaleX = boxes[i].scaleY = boxes[i].y / stage.stageHeight + 0.5;
          addChild(boxes[i]);    
        }
    }
  }
}

import flash.display.Sprite;
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import flash.events.*;

class Box extends Sprite {
   public function Box() {
       graphics.beginFill(0);
       graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFF0000);
       graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
       addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);

   }   

   private function onAdded(e:Event):void{
     // randomize the box position
     x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
     y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
     animate();
   }
   // animate to a random place on the screen over and over
   private function animate():void{
        var rx:Number = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth,
            ry:Number = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
       TweenLite.to(this, 3, {x : rx, y : ry, onComplete : animate});
   }

}
```